# Setting the CLASSPATH from Cygwin

Tags: java, bash, cygwin, classpath

I use Eclipse to develop Java so I have a folder full of Eclipse Java Project folders. The /bin folder resides in each folder, so to run the project from Cygwin, the classpath must be set (on my system) to: "E:/programming/java/workspace/SomeProject/bin". Since there are ~40 projects in my folder, I'd rather make a script to add the paths to the CLASSPATH. My script seems to add the paths to CLASSPATH, but when I try to run Java I get a class not found error. In my .bashrc here is my script:

```
JAVAWORKSPACE="/cygdrive/e/programming/java/workspace/*"
BIN="/bin;"
for f in $JAVAWORKSPACE
do
    if [ -d $f ] ; then
        export CLASSPATH="$f$BIN$CLASSPATH"
    fi
done
```

When I start Cygwin and echo $CLASSPATH, all of the directories show up, but java can't find the classes. I have also tried `JAVAWORKSPACE="E:\programming\java\workspace\*` but this resulted in nothing being added to CLASSPATH. If I go through the Windows settings and manually enter "E:/programming/java/workspace/MyProject/bin" to the CLASSPATH, command line Java has no trouble finding the classes. What's up with this? I'm not sure if it's a problem with the script or if CLASSPATH doesn't like unix-style paths. If I need to add windows paths, please help me change my script to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Cygwin set up right now, but I ran into this problem a number of years ago. Java knows nothing about Cygwin pathnames, and bash treats a single backslash as an escape character, stripping it before it can be transmitted to java(c). If you do

```
echo E:\programming\java\workspace\*
```

You'll see it outputs E:programmingjavaworkspace*, not what you're expecting. The key is to either escape the escape chars, like

```
E:\\programming\\java\\workspace\\*
```

or even better, use [cygpath](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) like [this](http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2008/03/10/java_bash_cygwin.html).